# Dynamic Form Validations in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I am Struggle With Dynamic Form Validation In My Current Project, in my Form Having Two Fields like User Name and Email, Both Are Mandatory.

If User Click Add-More(Up to 2 times only) Button Then Same above fields are came. those two fields are also Mandatory. if user removes those fields validation will not be work

I Already Wrote those 2 fields(3 times) just, I Kept ng-hide and ng-show,
And My Code is below,

```
enter code here
```

I have Added My Code To Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ErJl2Kg8maOn5GLaz9mb?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-required="showUser2"` instead of just `required`.

Comment: @HaRdik.. Can You please Guide Me How To Write.. My Above Code Using ng-repeat

Comment: Example: [Click here for Example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform) Try this example.

Comment: @HaRdik.. I follow Example as u mentioned. In My Database there is 3 records. then it comes 3 times. its looks fine. But In Another Situation In My DB There is No records. In This Case, there is nothing to display(including Form also). But I Need those 2 fileds 3 times (if having data or not).. if there is no data. then user will be added to db. if data is there then user may be chance to update the data. please guide me what can i do.

Comment: check in your controller if the result from post method that return data the list is empty, just push into your list one empty object and you will have the empty form there

Comment: @DianaR.., As You Said, if Data is empty, push one empty object, I am getting some error, My Code is Like This,                                                  If Having Data in My DB then 
if (response.data != "fail") {
        $scope.formDataTwo.premiumusers = response.data;
   }else if(response.data == "fail"){                        $scope.formDataTwo.premiumusers.push( {'user_id' : '','username':'','email':'','designation':'','image':''});
                    
                })
                }     Is This Correct Way ?? Please Guide me With Correct Solution

Comment: I would check if response.status == 200 cause the way you have it here, you should send from backend data="fail" which is not ok. But the code you have is the ok. Just make sure you have initialized the `$scope.formDataTwo = {}` and `$scope.formDataTwo.premiumusers = []` somewhere in your controller

Comment: I am agreed with @DianaR.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid to use ng-hide or ng-show. 
Prepare on model i.e. JSON Array and bind using ng-repeat and write associated code in JavaScript.

Example: [Click here for Example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform)

Answer (score 0):

In an AngularJS-form a field is still required even when its hidden.
That means when you hide your required form input field with `ng-hide` or `ng-show` then the AngularJS FormController `completeProfile` still treats the form as `$invalid`.

To get dynamic forms how you want them you can use `ng-if` to hide your unwanted input fields. Input fields inside of a `ng-if` are not considered by the form validation logic.

I updated your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dq3OZULm4TjUyf2eedPX?p=preview). The submit button is only shown when the form is valid.